# OpenCL haning in clEnqueueReadBuffer

Tags: opensuse, opencl

As follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77958881/16031219) where I my last code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 210
#include "CL/cl.h"

char* program_src = "__kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)\n"
"{\n"
"const int i = get_global_id (0);\n"
"y [i] = a * x [i];\n"
"}\n";

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platform_ids[16];
    cl_uint platform_count;

    if (clGetPlatformIDs(16, &platform_ids, &platform_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl platform(s) found\n", platform_count);

    if (platform_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("choosing platform 0...\n");

    cl_device_id device_ids[16];
    cl_int device_count;
    if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_ids[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 16, &device_ids, &device_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl device(s) found on platform 0\n", device_count);

    if (device_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_device_id device = device_ids[0];

    printf("** running test **\n");

    cl_int cl_fehler;
    cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCommandQueue\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, 0, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Replace 1 mit Zahlen von Gärate IDs
    printf("Am clCreateProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &program_src, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clBuildProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateKernel\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "SAXPY", &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem eingabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem ausgabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_float eingabe_data[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    printf("Am clEnqueueWriteBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, eingabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &eingabe_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &eingabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &ausgabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_float f = 2.0;
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_float), &f);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clEnqueueNDRangeKernel\n");
    const size_t globalWorkSize[3] = { 10, 0, 0 };
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    clFinish(queue);

    printf("Am clEnqueueReadBuffer\n");
    cl_float ausgabe_data[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 };
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, ausgabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &ausgabe_data[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // No point in share the rest of the code because the problem is being happening here
}
```

Is the last code that I got with all the corrections given so far, and the help says that there is no error that could find in this last iteration of the code.

The host is openSUSE Leap 15.5 x86_64 on an AMD ATI 04:00.0 Lucienne and AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 1.800GHz with AMD rocm drivers installed systemwide.

I am compiling with `cc src/main.c -lOpenCL -I/opt/rocm-6.0.0/include/ -L/opt/rocm-6.0.0/lib/ -o test`

And I have the `rocm-opencl-sdk` package installed from [here](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/sles.html) which is the vendors (AMD's) official page.